# TYPO3: Howto show records from a folder outside the page tree

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

In my TYPO3 installaion I have configured two websites in two separate page trees. Now I would like to show a record of a custom extension in website A but the record is stored in the page tree of website B.

This is the showAction in my controller:

```
public function showAction(\Vendor\Extension\Domain\Model\Event $event)
{
    $this->view->assign('event', $event);
}
```

In the repository I disabled the storage page restriction with the following lines of code:

```
class EventRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{
    public function initializeObject()
    {
        $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings::class);
        $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(false);
        $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
    }
}
```

Showing a record on website A which is stored in the page tree of website A, works without any problems. But as soon as I try to load a record of the page tree of website B on website A it fails.

So is it possible to show records which are stored outside of the page tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EventRepository has nothing to do with the parameter resolving for the `showAction()`. This should just work when given an uid of an event.

I suspect you also use routeEnhancers and maybe you chose ['eval: uniqueInSite'](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug.html#eval) for the slug configuration? - in that case try without routeEnhancers to verify.

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely right, the problem is the `eval: uniqueInSite` for the slug! So I changed it to `eval: unique` and it is working! Thanks a lot!